# json.unmarshal() - return nil

Tags: json, go

I get normal slice a bytes from base (slice maked by json.Marshal) and try decode them, but json.unmarshal() - return nil

Code :

```
coded := redis.LoadFromBase()
uncoded := json.Unmarshal(coded, &p)

fmt.Println("Bytes:", coded)
fmt.Println("Unmarshalled:", uncoded)
```

Returned:

```
Bytes: [123 34 84 105 116 108 101 34 58 34 97 34 44 34 67 111 110 116 101 110 116 34 58 34 98 34 125]
Unmarshalled: <nil>
```

LoadFromBase() works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are printing the error returned by [`json.Unmarshal`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) not the actual decoded value. It is `nil` so everything is fine.

It should be:

```
coded := redis.LoadFromBase()
err := json.Unmarshal(coded, &p)
if (err != nil) {
    // handle error here
}

fmt.Println("Bytes:", coded)
fmt.Println("Unmarshalled:", p)
```